# Conversion TDateTime to TDate

Tags: date, datetime, delphi

I have to prepared `TDate` variable from given data. I tried to do that with:

```pascal
EncodeDate(2023, 10, 14)
```

but I need to `TDate` format and I get `TDateTime`. Is there any simple way to convert it to `TDate`?

Comment: I don't understand the problem you have. If you have a variable, e.g. `d: TDate`, and you assign `d := EncodeDate(2023, 10, 14);`, doesnt `d` then contain the date 2023.10.14? Please show complete code that reveals the problem.

Comment: The definition of EncodeDate (https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.EncodeDate) is showing that this function reurn `TDateTime`, but if you use a `TDate` variable, you have already automatically performed the conversion. You can work with the `d:tDate` variable and you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: And in any case, both `TDateTime` and `TDate` are defined as `Double`, so at runtime, there's generally no difference. (But the compiler may use the static type at compile-time to make decisions. Maybe a plain `TDate(EncodeDate(2023, 10, 14))` will work for you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know the integer number of TDateTime is Date. so TDate can be Trunc(TDateTime).

Comment: We also know, that the result of EncodeDate does not contain any fractional part, so even Trunc isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: The fact that `TDateTime` is an alias for `Double` is an implementation detail. Using `DateOf()` would be more readable than using `Trunc()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would not call something an implementation detail that has been clearly documented for such a long time, e.g. at the [second link](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.TDateTime#Description) that Kai gave in his answer. Though I agree that `DateOf()` does make the intent much clearer than `Trunc()`.